# static import not working in Groovy 1.7.4?

Tags: groovy

I can't get static imports to work in Groovy. Is this supposed to work?

(I'm running Groovy 1.7.4 on Windows)

Constants.groovy:

```
package foo

class Constants {
    static final PI = 3.14
}
```

Test.groovy:

```
package foo
import static foo.Constants.PI

class Test {
    static main(args) {
        println("pi=" + PI)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Both files are stored in the same directory "foo".

When I try to run this I get:

```
groovy -cp . foo\Test.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PI for class: foo.Test
        at foo.Test.main(Test.groovy:6)
```

Comment: This is suppose to work - the issue comes most probably from your compilation command.

Comment: think you should look at your directory structure... Agree with rocb

Comment: Both Groovy files are stored in the same directory "foo".

As ataylor has commented below, the "groovy -cp . foo\Test.groovy" succeeds if you first run "groovyc foo/Constants.groovy". I don't think this should be necessary.

Comment: Same problem with Groovy 1.7.5

Answer (score 1):

This problem was reported as issue [[Groovy-4386]](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4386), and is now fixed in Groovy 1.7.6

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with groovy's dependency resolution.  You can work around it by forcing it to compile Constants.groovy first, like so:

```
groovyc foo/Constants.groovy
groovy foo/Test.groovy
```

EDIT: downgrading groovy to version 1.7.3 also solves this.

Comment: i tested this code... without multiple compiles as you have listed and it runs just fine, I believe the files are just not in the right directory

Comment: It's definitely a real problem.  It failed for me with the same error as the original poster with groovy 1.7.4 on linux.  The error doesn't occur with groovy 1.7.3.